# Groovy metaclass add multiple methods based on invocation order not mock

Tags: groovy, spock

I am trying to overwrite method Call on the groovy sql class and i am able to do it.But i need to have different implementations based on order.

```
 Sql.metaClass.call = {String sql, List params, Closure c -> c(mockResultSet)}      //first time should call this method
 Sql.metaClass.call = {String sql, List params, Closure c -> c(expectedLookupId)}   //second time should call this method.
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [mock out return of a method base on the number of invocation only in spock](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26737268/mock-out-return-of-a-method-base-on-the-number-of-invocation-only-in-spock)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to implement it would be using an internal flag in the class. 
Then call the different implementations based on the flag.

```
Sql.metaClass.first = true
Sql.metaClass.call = {String sql, List params, Closure c ->    
   if (first){
     c(mockResultSet)
     first = false
   }else{
     c(expectedLookupId)
   }
}
```

Comment: What if i want to have these calls.

            Sql.metaClass.call = { String sql, List params, Closure c ->c(mockResultSet) // first time}

           Sql.metaClass.call = { String sql, List params -> params } //second time

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Joachim for the suggestion.This worked for me.

```
    def counter = 1
    Sql.metaClass.call = {String sql, List params, Closure c ->
        if(counter ==1 ) {
            c(mockResultSet)
            counter++;
        }else{
            c(expectedLookupId)
        }
    }
```